# Preprocessor directives from C++ code (_VARIADIC_MAX)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive

Please how to define preprocessor directive _VARIADIC_MAX=10 from C++ code? For now I set it in Property Page -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Definitions but I need it in each project. Will be cool to define it one time in some common.h file and use in every project by including such header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#define _VARIADIC_MAX 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this definition for current user throught user property sheet:
Open one of your project, select View -> Property Manager.
Then open property Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user, and add your constant like earler (Common Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions).
Save and restart visual studio.